# parseInt always returns NaN?

Tags: javascript, nan, parseint

long story short, i was trying to validate a phone field. ive added
the `isNaN` and `parseInt` for checking the `" "` in the field but that said

This below never validates to true..what am i missing?

```
if(isNaN(parseInt(phone))){
        error.text("Sorry but this phone field requires numbers only");
        return false;
    } else {
    return true;

    }
```

it always fails...it never reads true even when i enter a number in the field and submit.
i always get the error mssg.

***EDIT:*** I am testing input values from a form, `phone` is the name of the field.

Comment: Works for me, e.g. with phone="5". What are your test input values?

Comment: yeah sorry, im testing input vals from a form

Comment: You should include your html here in the question too.  That might help us debug it.

Comment: -1 for not including the actual values that you're testing. I'm *guessing* that `phone` is an HTML input element reference instead of  the `.value` of it.

Comment: But which number did you enter that gave the error instead of true?

Comment: I'm wondering if a domnode is getting evaluated rather than the form value - hence never returning true since parseInt on an object will always not be a number.

Comment: lols @ Phrogz...thanks...i edited post. @ Bergi, i first seubmited the form to test for the "" and then just typed random numbers, and then letters and it always throws me the error mssg

Comment: @webnesto Yep you were correct, somehow i thought that just giving the field name an id would resolve it but it didnt. like it treated it as a whole "object" so i changed it to if(isNaN(parseInt(phone.val()))) and it now works

Answer (score 14):

Various ways to coerse JS strings to numbers, and their consequences:

[image: Results of converting various strings using the above techniques]
<sub>(source: [phrogz.net](http://phrogz.net/JS/string_to_number.png))</sub>

I personally use `*1` as it is short to type, but still stands out (unlike the unary +), and either gives me what the user typed or fails completely. I only use `parseInt()` when I *know* that there will be non-numeric content at the end to ignore, or when I need to parse a non-base-10 string.

**Edit**: Based on your comment, if using `phone.val()` fixed it then

1. You were using jQuery (which you never mentioned, and should have), and
2. You actually had/have a jQuery object, wrapping one or more DOM elements (probably just one).

Whenever you do `var foo = $('…');` then the `foo` variable references a jQuery object of one or more elements. You can get the first actual DOM element from this via `var fooEl = foo[0];` or `var fooEl = foo.get(0);`…but even then you *still* have a DOM element and not a particular property of that.

For form inputs, you need to get the `.value` from the DOM element, which is what the jQuery `.val()` method does.

Answer (score 11):

`parseInt` is a bit odd at times:

```
> parseInt("123-456-789")
123
```

Fortunately you can probably solve your case with:

```
> Number("123-456-789")
NaN
```

Answer (score 9):

parseInt only returns NaN if the first character cannot be converted to a number.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt

Answer (score 2):

I've seen `Number()` suggested, but that will still allow things like `-21` or `123.456`. The best way to check for the absence of non-digits in a string is like this:

```js
function hasNonDigit(str){
  return /\D/g.test(str.toString());
}

console.log(hasNonDigit("123-456-7890"));
console.log(hasNonDigit("1234567890"));
```