# Replace with the regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

What regular expression I need to use to correct

```
if (text.indexOf("+") != -1) {
            action = "+";
        } else if (text.indexOf("-") != -1) {
            action = "-";
        } else if (text.indexOf("*") != -1) {
            action = "*";
        } else if (text.indexOf("/") != -1) {
            action = "/";
        }
```

this code
?

EDIT:

and how can I improve this code:

```
switch (action) {
        case "+":
            result = parseInt(array[0]) + parseInt(array[1]);
            break;
        case "-":
            result = parseInt(array[0]) - parseInt(array[1]);
            break;
        case "*":
            result = parseInt(array[0]) * parseInt(array[1]);
            break;
        case "/":
            result = parseInt(array[0]) / parseInt(array[1]);
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
```

Sorry for dull questions I am new in js.

Comment: are you matching against position in the string, or you just need to match?

Comment: wow @ your second bit of code, that's kind of what `eval` does, like the only time you should actually use it...

Comment: I know.I am learning js and in this sample I am writing simple customEval(text) function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use either of these:

```
var action = text.replace(/.*([+*/-]).*/,'$1');

var match  = /[*+/-]/.exec(text);
var action = match && match[0];
```

If there's the possibility of newlines in your `text` then change the first to:

```
var action = text.replace(/[\d\D]*([+*/-])[\d\D]*/,'$1');
```

**Edit**: You can improve your `switch` statement by using, e.g.

```
// allow floating point values, and also 
// don't accidentally interpret "011" as octal
array[0]*1 + array[1]*1;
```

For more details on why `parseInt` is probably bad, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10184402/405017).

You can also remove the superfluous `default` section of your case statement. However, I suspect that your desired "improvement" was making fewer lines. Given that `=-*/` are *operators* in JavaScript (and not methods), I cannot think of any way to avoid having four calculations (i.e. a `switch` or `if/else if`).

*Whereas in Ruby you could, for example, use `array[0].send(action,array[1])` to cover all four cases ;)*

Comment: OK, I was about to post `action = text.match('[-+/*]')[0];` I think you might need to move your `-` to the start or end of the character set so it doesn't look like a range.