# React useState: how to update object and use variable's number value as key?

Tags: reactjs, use-state

I have a state hook defined as:

```
  const [formState, setFormState] = useState({
    officeHourStart: "",
    officeHourEnd: "",
    timezone: "",
    doctorQuotas: {}
  });
```

and it is initiated like:

```
const mapUserIdQuotas = {0: 12, 1: 15};

setFormState({
  officeHourStart: settings.officeHourStart,
  officeHourEnd: settings.officeHourEnd,
  timezone: settings.timezone,
  doctorQuotas: mapUserIdQuotas
})
```

Now I want to update the `doctorQuotas` part of it.
Specifically, I need to update the `{0: 12, 1: 15}` to `{0: 12, 1: 20}`

```
  const updateDoctorQuota = (event) => {
    const id = parseInt(event.target.id);
    const value = parseInt(event.target.value); 
    setFormState({...formState, doctorQuotas: { ...formState.doctorQuotas, id: value}});
  }
```

This does not work since the result `formState` would be:

```
{
  officeHourStart: ... ,
  officeHourEnd:  ... ,
  timezone: ... ,
  doctorQuotas: {0: 12, 1: 15, id: 20}
}
```

I tried:

```
  const updateDoctorQuota = (event) => {
    const id = parseInt(event.target.id);
    const value = parseInt(event.target.value); 
    setFormState({...formState, doctorQuotas: { ...formState.doctorQuotas, [id]: value}});
  }
```

Then it becomes:

```
{
  officeHourStart: ... ,
  officeHourEnd:  ... ,
  timezone: ... ,
  doctorQuotas: {0: 12, 1: 15, NaN: 20}
}
```

How can I use the integer value of variable `id` to update the corresponding key-value pair?

Comment: Did you try logging what is the ID each time updateDoctorQuota  is called? Is it possible to share a run-snippet?

Comment: I suggest using a state object to store doctorQuotas values, then update this state object instead of updating the formState. It will be much easier to access and change key, values in that case

Comment: something must be wrong with id because [id]: value should work. try to console.log(id) and see what's there.

Comment: The object should update fine, the problems is in `event.target.id` that is not valid, try not parsing as int and just pass `event.target.id` or simply make sure that `event.target` has an `id`. Check this post [parseInt() returns NaN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10184368/parseint-always-returns-nan)